# (python utf-8) using 'à','ç','é','è','ê','ë','î','ô','ù'

Tags: python, utf-8, diacritics

I am having trouble with accent in python

I wrote # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- so it can recognize the accent. 
But still sometime it doesn't work. I get '?' and when I use it after I get an error " SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' "

Why ? What should I change? Thanks

(doesn't work for all those characters 'à','ç','é','è','ê','ë','î','ô','ù',"‘","’")

this is my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

testList = ['à','ç','é','è','ê','ë','î','ô','ù',"‘","’"]

testCharacter = raw_input('test a character : ') # example : é

print(testCharacter) # getting é
print(testCharacter[0]) # getting ? 
print(testCharacter + testCharacter[0]) # getting é?

testCharacterPosition = testList.index(testCharacter) 

print(testCharacterPosition) #getting 2
```

this is the result on my console :

```
test a character : é
é
?
é?
2
```

Comment: Why are you using `raw_input()` in Python 3?

Comment: Looks like you're a beginner, so why do you use Python 2 that has reached end-of-life already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are still using python2 (you should consider switching to python3 since python2 is discontinued).

If pasted some utf8 string, it is encoded and therefore consists of multiple characters, e.g.:

```
>>> s = 'à'
>>> s
'\xc3\xa0'
>>> s[0]
'\xc3'
```

Of course this will print an question mark since one alone doesn't make the full character:

```
>>> print(s + s[0])
à�
```

you can convert this to a unicode string, which then consists of one character:

```
>>> s.decode('utf-8')
u'\xe0'
>>> print(s.decode('utf-8'))
à
```

You can get around decode when directly using unicode strings in py2:

```
>>> s = u'à'
>>> s
u'\xe0'
```

Better would be to use python3, which simplifies the whole thing to:

```
>>> s = 'à'
>>> s
'à'
>>>
```